# Can Query results be put onto a text field of a form?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Can the results of a query be put into a text box on a form?  I have a form that I would like to put the last "Order Number" (which is a text field) into a textbox on the form.  I have a query written that brings up the last order number -- SELECT Max(SwitchingProcedure.OrderNumber) AS MaxOfOrderNumber FROM SwitchingProcedure-- Can this result be put on a form that is bound to this table.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the DLookup function to retrieve a column value from any specified table or query.

In the control source of your text box, use: =DLookup("[Enter column name from query here]","[Enter name of your query]")

You can also add criteria to the DLookUp to limit the result to a particular row, but your query should only return one row anyway so it's not needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer! In this case, probably can go with =DMax("OrderNumber", "SwitchingProcedure") as the ControlSource in the textbox and avoid the intermediate query altogether, though.

Answer (score -3):

yes we can put the jquery result in to the textfield.use below code

```
$("text-field").val(jquery_result)
```